# issue in installing ADT 8.0.1 in eclipse galileo

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

In eclipse i updated installed packages for Android SDK Tools from revision 2 to revision 8.

Now when i am trying to install the ADT plugin 8.0.1 (help->install new sw).

I select the path of the zip folder in my local (ADT-8.0.1.zip) and check on all Android DDMS,Android Development Tools,Android Hierarchy Viewer

and click on next button

The screen shows something as " Calculating requirements and dependencies " and gets stuck there.

Pls suggest where am i going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its not stuck its slow, you should wait.

Comment: Have been waiting since over an hour now.Does it require so much time?

Comment: depends on your internet connection, it tries to resolve dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens from time to time. Don't ask me why tho.

Just try it again and it should work.

Comment: Yes it worked with the same steps. Thanks Octavian and Ismail.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the Eclipse is over-zealous in checking ALL-THE-FREAKING Dependencies available. A possible solution that worked for me can be found in this [post of mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/723fcd65f0456214).
It tells to do all the updates before installing any new plugins.

**Steps**

- Go to Windows / Preferences, select Install / Update and then click on the 
  link for Automatic Updates, change the settings to: 
     Look for updates each time the platform is started 
     Search for updates and notify me when they are available 
     Notify me once about updates Click on apply and then Ok.
- Restart Eclipse, let the auto-update run. Then go to Help/ Check for
  Updates; and then install whatever updates it presents, mostly it is:

  ```
        Java Development 
       Web and Java EE Development
  ```
- Click Install and wait for the updates to be downloaded / installed. Restart 
  Eclipse when asked.

Done, worked for me in every case(Subversion and Android).